# Does Amazon S3 counts whole file size in bandwidth for HEAD call

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Does Amazon S3 counts whole file size in bandwidth for HEAD call? I searched on the Amazon S3 documentation but there is nothing mentioned regarding this. My application data usage on S3 is very high. I checked the access logs of bucket, but it's mostly HEAD calls.

Answer (score 1):

On S3 you pay for two components:

1. Bandwidth usage.. HEAD call will not contribute much to this.
2. Number of requests... HEAD calls will count under this cost head.

I will suggest you to Enable Detailed Billing from My Account section.. This will save cost for each AWS service in your S3 bucket in CSV format. You do not paying anything extra for this service except S3 storage charge for that file. Download the CSV file and filter for S3 charges. It will show you demarcation between these two charges.